# Community♦ shouldn't be asking people to show "working code" on RPG.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, community-bot

I've just discovered a comment from [the Community bot](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) under an answer that says the following:

[image: the comment, quoted below]

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations. – Community♦ 22 mins ago

Now, the answer has some quality issues and could do with citations, but... this is not a programming site. We don't add “working code” to our answers and “documentation citations” is not exactly how I'd phrase a request to quote some rules and/or personal experience of what works in practice. This seems to be a Stack Overflow experiment that's spilled over here incorrectly or without the necessary changes.

I can't flag this comment for removal, either—I'm blocked from doing so by the system itself:

[image: screenshot of a flag dialog where I've attempted to flag the comment for removal with the reason “this isn't a programming site.” I am stopped from doing so by the system which shows a message, quoted below.]

> This comment will be automatically removed by the system when the post is corrected.

Could these comments please be switched off here?

[Here's a link to the comment.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76787/can-a-black-dragon-hatchling-be-raised-to-be-good-or-is-it-inherently-evil/191102#comment514243_191102)

Comment: Reported on Meta.SE here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369052/please-make-the-canned-feedback-options-in-the-new-first-question-answer-queues/369064#369064

Comment: [Flagging issue reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067/674198)

Comment: nice catch doppel!  